# Expected value of Markov chain after nth steps

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

A Markov chain $\{ X_n, n \geqslant 0\}$ with states 0, 1, 2 has the transition probability matrix $$P= \begin{bmatrix} \frac12 & \frac13 & \frac16 \\ 0 & \frac12 & \frac23 \\ \frac12 & 0 & \frac12 \end{bmatrix}$$

If $P\{X_0 =0 \} = P\{X_0=1\}=\frac14$ find $E[X_3]$

How to answer this question?

Comment: Ask on [math.se] instead.

Comment: We discourage questions that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  Instead, I encourage you to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in asking about how to solve exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[X_3] = 0\cdot P(X_3=0) + 1\cdot P(X_3=1) + 2\cdot P(X_3=2)$ Hence
$$E[X_3]= \frac14 P^3_{01} + \frac14P^3_{11} + \frac12P^3_{21} + 2\left[ \frac14P^3_{02} +\frac14P^3_{12} + \frac12P^3_{22}\right]$$